# How to de-allocating the memory allocated using std::memory_resource in static method without changing the below function signature

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How can we de-allocate the memory allocated in static member function using `std::memory_resource::allocate()`?

I tried using deleter function passing to the `unique_ptr` instead of `default_delete`. In that case it is freeing the allocator memory.

The problems are:

- I am not sure about the allocator object lifetime till the end of `unique_ptr` going out of scope
- I don't want to change the static function signature below form using deleter method.

eg:

```
static std::unique_ptr<base,std::functional<void(base*)>> create(std::pmr::memory_resource* all)
  {
    void* ptr = all->allocate(sizeof(base));
    std::unique_ptr<base, std::function<void(base*)> up(new base(), [&all] 
     (base* b){ all->deallocate(b,sizeof(base));
    return std::move(up);
  }
```

//Actual source code

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC 
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class base
{
  int val = 0;
public:
  base()
  {

  }
  ~base()
  {
    cout << "dest" << endl;
  }
  static std::unique_ptr<base> create(std::pmr::memory_resource* all)
  {
    void* ptr = all->allocate(sizeof(base));
    return std::unique_ptr<base>(new(ptr) base());
  }
};

int main()
{
  {
    {
      std::pmr::memory_resource* all = std::pmr::get_default_resource();
      auto b1 = base::create(all);
      auto b2 = base::create(all);
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I want to free the memory allocated in the static method without modifying the function signature(means adding the deleter function to the `unique_ptr`).

Suggest any solution to solve this problem and pls also mention different ways of freeing the memory allocated in this sample code via `allocate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocated with [`std::pmr::memory_resource::allocate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/memory_resource/allocate) has to be deallocated using [`std::pmr::memory_resource::deallocate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/memory_resource/deallocate).

So doing the following is wrong:

```
void* ptr = all->allocate(sizeof(base));
return std::unique_ptr<base>(new(ptr) base());
```

The problem here is that the `unique_ptr` would call `delete` on the pointer hold by `ptr`, and that is not valid. As of that, you have to provide a custom deleter, there is no way around that.

As it is not clear what problem you want to solve with `memory_resource::allocate` it is not really possible to tell how you could solve it. The allocation of memory per object seems very strange, at least, and indicates that your approach is wrong.

Comment: void* ptr = all->allocate(sizeof(base));
return std::unique_ptr<base>(new(ptr) base()); why this code is wrong ? can you pls explain more on this.As per my understanding unique_ptr will call the base destructor when it is going out of scope.My requirement is, i have to create a base object inside the static function using allocator object . Allocator object will be passed as input argument to the static function.When my unique_ptr is going out of scope it has to deallocate the memory automatically.

Comment: @Mahendra As I said the default behavior of a `unique_ptr` is that it will call `delete` on the pointer that it is managing and this is only valid if that pointer was allocated using `new`. If you do `base * b = new(ptr) base()`, then you are not allowed to do `delete b`, you are only allowed to call the destructor on it `b->~base();`.

Comment: I tried to store the allocator pointer object & ptr object inside vector.when unique_ptr is going out of scope it will call the destructor of base().Inside base destructor i am deallocating the memory using allocator object stored inside vector & assigning ptr object to null. But the problem is unique_ptr is throwing exception after execution of base destructor().From that i understood that unique_ptr is trying to free the memory .eg: vector<std::tuple<base*&,Allocator*>> container to store allocator & base*.

Comment: @Mahendra in your posted code you do `std::unique_ptr up(new base(), [&all](base* b){ all->deallocate(b,sizeof(base));` so in your example you call, `all->deallocate` on a pointer that is not created with  `all->allocate`, but with `new base()`.